# How do I see what distribution lists I'm subscribed to in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I get work emails because I'm subscribed to various lists. Is there some way to see what lists I'm subscribed to?

Comment: Are you an IT administrator or regular employee? Do you have Outlook web apps available (OWA)?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The easiest way is to do the following:

1) Open Outlook

2) Click the search people field (towards the upper right):
[image]

3) Search for your name/users name

4) Select "membership" tab and all groups you're a member of are listed below.

[image]

From OWA (if available) you can simply go to the 'options' cog in the upper right of the screen and then on the left side select 'groups' and you'll see your group membership

[image]

Comment: This is very helpful for the desktop client. I can't seem to find an equivalent on the web interface - anyone know if it can be done on the web?

Comment: @jlbriggs https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-and-manage-your-groups-in-outlook-on-the-web-23462715-f405-416a-807f-7e9d02ae5ca9#:~:text=View%20and%20manage%20groups%20you're%20a%20member%20of&text=At%20the%20top%20of%20the,email%20conversations%20in%20the%20group.

Comment: Is there any update for 2020?  The screenshot from step 4 seems to be outdated by now unfortunately.  Thanks.

Comment: Does not work for Outlook for Mac version 16

Answer (score 5):

For OWA (Outlook Web Access) as of 2021 go to:

- Cog icon (top right) > View all Outlook settings > General > Distribution groups

It may take a while to load but should eventually show 'Distribution groups I belong to'

Answer (score 0):

This is how I was able to check if I am a member of the list. However, the list was pretty small, so maybe this method would not work for larger ones.

1. Click on New Email.
2. In the "To" section, type in the distribution list you would like to check and click Enter.
3. Click on the plus sign to the left of the list name and it will expand to show all the members of the DL.